# Send AJAX on click, but still go to URL of href

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting the following:

When a user clicks a link, I want to update a specific column of a specific table in the database via ajax.  BUT I still want the user to be redirected to the `href="<url>"` of the link.

I tried jQuery without `return false;` but then the ajax doesn't work.

I tried with `return false;` but then the page obviously doesn't redirect to the url as I wanted.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send information about clicked link to the server before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295354/send-information-about-clicked-link-to-the-server-before-redirect)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do your AJAX call, then set `document.location` when done.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var href = this.href;  // get href from link
    e.preventDefault();  // don't follow the link
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/site',
        data: {some: data},
        success: function(){
            document.location = href;  // redirect browser to link
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: window.location = href; would better. Keeps history and I think document.location is only used for redirection on gecko (firefox) browsers. (not sure on this one)

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize these actions yourself.  In the event handler first run your AJAX request, then lookup the href from the tag and use a location redirect to take the client to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirect code in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(){
    $(location).attr('href',url); // You URL inserted
  }
});
```

Comment: I've never seen `$(location).attr('href',url);` before.  Seems to work, but I'd prefer `document.location = url;`.  It doesn't require the overhead of calling jQuery.

Comment: @Rocket True. A possibility, but your answer might be simpler.