# HTML Anchor tag redirect link after ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, anchor, preventdefault

I'm trying to write a method to catch user clicks on a site menu, but I want the process to be silent for the user, mainly, that when a user hovers over an anchor tag, it would behave normally (showing the link it contains). I've tried in various ways to do this, and I almost have it working now, my code is as follows:

```
<div class="selectNode" id="selectNode_1" style="color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47); ">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="selectAnchor" style="color: rgb(229, 229, 229); ">
    Google
  </a>
  <img class="childImage" src="icon.png">
</div>
```

And in jQuery, I have:

```
$(".selectAnchor, .menuAnchor").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    //event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localsite/menuRedirect.php',
      data: {id:0, module:'Module',source:'Source'},
      complete: function(data){
        console.log("DONE");
        return true;
      }
    });
});
```

The link redirects to the selected page, but the ajax code never finishes, thus never registers the user's click.

I tried using event.preventDefault, but there is no way to resume the cancelled event.

Part of the problem comes from extra functionality, say, most users right click on the anchor tag to open in a new tab (or use control + click, or middle click), and using something like

```
<a href="javascript:saveClick(o)">Google</a>
```

is not allowed on the site (for security reasons).

Any suggestions how this can be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault`, then on success, use `location.href = self.href`

```
$(".selectAnchor, .menuAnchor").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localsite/menuRedirect.php',
      data: {id:0, module:'Module',source:'Source'},
      complete: function(data){
        console.log("DONE");
        location.href = self.href;
      }
    });
});
```

Or make use of the context property to remove `var self = this`

```
$(".selectAnchor, .menuAnchor").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      context: this,
      url: 'http://localsite/menuRedirect.php',
      data: {id:0, module:'Module',source:'Source'},
      complete: function(data){
        console.log("DONE");
        location.href = this.href;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried something similar, and works on the case of left click, but control + left click, or middle click opens the link on the same window. Some of the links also contain target="_blank", so this method would also not work on them.

Comment: If you want to preserve that functionality, there isn't much you can do. If you don't prevent the event from happening, your ajax request won't complete. If you prevent the event, that other functionality can't be preserved.

Comment: Have you considered making an intermediate page that redirects after tracking the exit?

Comment: You could change the href on click to your redirect page, then your redirect page records the action and redirects the user.

Comment: Seems similar to using a href="javascript:method()" approach, I tried it but since the mouseover text would not be the final link, it would asked to be removed. Unless there is a way to display another text

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this and now its almost running, now I only have to find a way to handle on right click + open in new tab (if it even is possible), but this will do for now!

Answer (score 2):

Latest chrome browser wont complete the ajax request. Since the browser page got new url request from the user, so browser will kill the thread immediately.

98% of times you can see that the ajax request got cancelled in a network tab.

So the solution is use sendBeacon API. This will perform a POST request asynchronously.
Google analytics uses this code to perform the event trackings (Ex: click).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

```
 navigator.sendBeacon("{{url}}", param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div class="selectNode" id="selectNode_1" style="color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47); ">
  <a href="#" class="selectAnchor" style="color: rgb(229, 229, 229); ">
    Google
  </a>
  <img class="childImage" src="icon.png">
</div>
```

Then this in jquery:

```
$(".selectAnchor, .menuAnchor").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    //event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localsite/menuRedirect.php',
      data: {id:0, module:'Module',source:'Source'},
      complete: function(data){
        console.log("DONE");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com"
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried something similar, and works on the case of left click, but control + left click, or middle click opens the link on the same window. Some of the links also contain target="_blank", so this method would also not work on them.

Comment: @desto - edited , this will work for sure , only thing is that you won't see the link on mouse over