# Javascript ajax request callback without waiting for response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know we can make a javascript ajax request from some server and it either receives the response or gives timeout error after some time.

Let's consider this scenario when we don't want to wait for the request rather the server would send a response(or we can say it would be another request from server to client) async at any time after getting the request and then call a javascript CB function with the response.

I am looking for ideas for how to go about it mainly supporting all modern browsers and if possible not relying on any 3rd party plugin except may be jQuery.

Comment: So you want the server to send signals to the client on the servers terms? Or spefically after the client sends a post / get?

Comment: Take a look into web sockets, the web socket protocol will enable you to stream data in either direction client->server, server->client. Take a look at http://socket.io/ a library that enables realtime communication between client & server using sockets or other available technologies.

Comment: You can start processing at server, return response to user that the request is in queue. Server completes request after some time and push results to client. This is a push mechanism and can be achieved using websockets, long polling (in old browsers), or you can use libraries like socket.io

Comment: @Glubus when the server receives a request, but don't push the processing results with the same request's response.
SatishGadhave: This push mechanism is what I am looking for, I hope I will find some native implementation for it.

Answer (score 0):

The main feature of Ajax is that it IS asynchronous by default, and your program will continue to run without waiting for the response.  So unless I'm misreading your question, it is what you need.

If you use jquery, then you pass in a callback function that will execute only when the server sends back a response.  You can specify a timeout in the settings, though I'm not sure what the maximum time you can provide without getting a timeout error.  But it will be several seconds, at least.

You can even specify different callbacks for success and fail as follows (adapted from the jquery ajax API, but added a timeout of 5 seconds):

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://www.some.url/",
  method: "GET",
  data: { some : stuff },
  dataType: "html",
  timeout: 5000
});

request.done(function( data ) {
  console.log( "SUCCESS: " + data );
});

request.fail(function() {
  console.log( "Request failed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question after 4 years. I dont remember in what context I asked this but for anyone who has the same query:

Http is a request/response protocol. Which means the client sends a request and the server responds to that request with some message/data. Thats the end of the story for that request.

In order for the server to trigger something on the clientside we will have to use something that keeps the connection to the server rather than ending the communication after getting the response. Socket.io is bi directional event driven library that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To update a cart (PHP Session storage and reserve the stock of items in database) on my online shop, I simply add a **timeout of 100ms** after calling it and **remove Success/Error callback**.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.some.url/',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    some : 'stuff' 
  },
  dataType: 'html',
  timeout: 100
});
```

> Note : It doesn't matter if some requests didn't arrive, because when the order is saved, an update of the whole cart is sent with a callback.
> **If your query needs acknowledge, don't use that solution !**

Answer (score -1):

I believe your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518363/possible-to-make-ajax-call-that-doesnt-return)
by Paul Tomblin. I use the answer provided by **gdoron**, which is also marked as the best solution, and also the comment by **AS7K**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "theURL",
    data: theData
});
```

NB: No `async` parameter provided.

Comment: Other's answer can't be used as your own answer. If you have an answer of your own, put it as a new answer, otherwise just share the link as a comment.

Comment: Yes. I did exactly as you have posted, that is referencing the authors and providing the link. Well I believe you should post how it ought to be done as many of us are not familiar with some of the unwritten rules of this platform.