# Synchronous wait for $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need a hyperlink to execute an Ajax call, and when that has completed, do the standard action for the hyperlink.

```
<a href="afterwards.html" target="_blank" onclick="return CallFirst();">Link</a>
```

The javascript function calls `$.ajax()`, waits for success or failure, then returns true.

```
function CallFirst()
{
    $deferred = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data
                });

    // **todo** WAIT until the Ajax call has responded.

    // Return true, which makes the <a> tag do it's standard action
    return true;
}
```

The code must wait for `$.ajax` to succeed, then return true from `CallFirst()`.

`$deferred.when()` terminates immediately. How can it be made to wait?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Anchor tag redirect link after ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500669/html-anchor-tag-redirect-link-after-ajax-request)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set `async` property to `false`

```
$deferred = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                async: false
            });
```

But it is really a better idea to use callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You could set async to false but better practice to use callback:

```
.done(function( success) {
    if (success) {
      doSomeThingElseNow();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use the build in ajax callbacks from jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```