# store data via ajax and then go to that URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, events

I am here for an help.

```
<a class="text" href="http://test.com?id=87"><img src="/2016/02/BlueFantasyThumb.jpg"><h3>Milky</h3></a>
```

When i click on this, i need to do certain ajax things that i know how to do. But the problem is i need to perform ajax and then go to that href link.

Upon clicking i know using e.preventDefault(); we can prevent default behaviour. But the case is i dont want to prevent this. I want to occur that event just after that ajax implementation without any obstruction in viewers point.

Any kind of inputs will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: you want to call the ajax on the link click right ?

Comment: Delete the href from UI. In the Javascript , call the click event for the anchor tag and perform ajax first. On Success , call the href.

Comment: yes. thanks for all inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send information about clicked link to the server before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295354/send-information-about-clicked-link-to-the-server-before-redirect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `href` value in a variable, call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent redirection and run your ajax code. In your ajax success callback, you can pick the `href` value and redirect to that link using javascript.

```
$("a.text").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var href = $(this).attr("href");
 $.ajax({
  url: URL,
  data: DATA,
  success: function(response){
   // your code here to be executed before redirecting
   window.location.href = href;
  }//success
 });//ajax
});//click
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Set html like

```
<a class="text" data-href="http://test.com?id=87"><img src="/2016/02/BlueFantasyThumb.jpg"><h3>Milky</h3></a>
```

2) add click event

```
$(".text").click(function() { // set ajax
   var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
   $.ajax({
     url: "ajax.php", // set required url here
   }).done(function() {
     alert("sucess")
     window.location.href = url;  // redirect page in ajax success
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change href to javascript:;

and then your ancor tag onclick event call a function of ajax call

inside ajax success function

write

window.location.href = "http://test.com?id=87";