# Add onclick handler to hyperlink tag to trigger ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink

I want to add ajax call on hyperlink tag "`a`", this ajax will only send some info to server and I don' have to get any return.
I tried something like this:

```
document.querySelector("#myId").onclick = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path',
        type: 'post',
        data: {key: 'value'},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

And I found that, if my "`a`" tag with a href-link like

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="myId">click</a>
```

My server WON"T get any info, and my fail callback function of ajax was triggered, but if I remove the href-link or replace it with `#` like

```
<a href="#" id="myId"></a>
<a id="myId"></a>
```

my server WILL get the info I send, and of course my success callback funciton was triggered

The fail callback function didn't return any error message, just a simple word **error**
Does anybody know what's going on and how to change the page and send ajax call in the same click?

By the way, I'm not prefer to put something like
`window.location.href = "https://www.google.com.tw"` in my success callback function, because in this case I'm maintain others' codes, I prefer to append my code down below rather than modified the already exist one, thanks!

Comment: If you click on a link, you will be redirect to another page, so no time to make ajax. The solution you mentionned work well, but if you want, you can pass the data to the other page and make the treatment here. But I don't know what you do with ajax so complicate to help you. Hope you understand my english

Comment: BTW, if your link shouldn't redirect a user to another page it should be a `<button>`.  Except if you really want to "cheat the user".

Comment: The reason I want to add ajax call on "a" tag is, I want to record the behavior of use(like which link they clicked), but I don't want to modified the code which is already exist. so I decide to add onclick function to "a" tag, which could record use click behavior by my code, also redirect user by original code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send information about clicked link to the server before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295354/send-information-about-clicked-link-to-the-server-before-redirect)

Comment: it looks similar but I guess the focus point it's a little bit different of each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should prevent the default behaviour (redirection) by adding `preventDefault()` :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelector("#myId").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api_url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {key: 'value'},
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="myId">click</a>
```

Comment: sorry bro I guess this isn't what I want, the ajax will call another url which is my api, not the href  attribute value on hyper-link tag, and I already fix the access-control problem by setting some parameter of chrome browser. I didn't use e.preventDefault(); but the redirection still working, so I guess the onclick function won't overwrite it

Comment: Yes i see, sorry too but the OP not clear enough... just about _I didn't use `e.preventDefault();` but the redirection still working_ so you should use it to prevent the redirection. (updated my answer).

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` solved your problem or not yet?

Comment: not yet, still get error return without any text but "error"

Comment: Wow, Sorry bro I put e.preventDefault() to the wrong place yesterday! it make redirection stop then I could use window.location.href after my ajax! That's amazing! thanks for help and sorry about my misunderstood.